# Error setting up ddd to debug bash scripts

Tags: linux, bash, debugging, installation, termcap

I am comparatively new to Linux. I am running Fedora 64 bit at my PC. I am having difficulty setting up ddd with bashdb. I am able to install it using yum but when I run it for bashdb, the software environment for ddd comes up but it keeps on working for infinite time, unless I manually kill it.

I used google to know what the problem is and came to know many people are having same problem, when using linux's package installers. It has bugs so I have to compile the latest source and install it manually. So I downloaded the source and tried to ./configure, it produced the following error and exited:

**configure: error: Cannot find termcap compatible library**

I searched again and found out I need termcap library at my PC, here:
https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-ddd/2013-01/msg00004.html
http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/unices/58299/

I used yum to install ncurses but found out it is already installed. Used locate to find the path of ncurses and passed it to configure using following commands:
sudo ./configure --with-termlib-libraries=/lib/libncurses.so.5
sudo ./configure --with-termlib-libraries=/lib/libncurses.so.5.9

Still, I am having the same error.

It is very frustrating because I have tried almost everything I found on internet. May be, there is a minor point that I am overlooking due to my inexperience. My main concern is to be able to debug complex bash scripts that I am going to develop in near future. I am not very comfortable with command line debugging i.e. without an interface. Any tips/advice that, can get me going with debugging with some other application may be, are also welcomed

Comment: why don't use (set -xv)?

Comment: I am more used to interactive debugging, like in eclipse/visual studio. I find it hard to read through the script output, and understand what's going on, when -xv is used. It is of course there as the last resort but I am looking for easier solution

Comment: as a help, ubuntu is much better than others for starting with linux...ddd is installed easily:sudo apt-get install ddd...if you use fedora problems would never leave you

Comment: @MortezaLSC thank you for the advice but I'm afraid my employers won't agree to moving their systems to ubuntu, in order to ease my debugging ;) Also, users are experiencing same problems with ubuntu as well. I guess ddd moderators need to have a serious look into this matter

Answer (score 1):

I installed the ncurses development package to get past this problem:

`sudo yum install ncurses-devel*`